# The intersection of open intervals.

Tags: general-topology

For $i=1,2, \cdots, n$, let $I_{i}=(a_i, b_i)$ be an open interval. Show that $\cap_{i=1}^n I_i$ is either the empty set or an open interval. Can anyone show me how to do this because this is slightly confusing.

Comment: What do you think the endpoints are?

Comment: Wouldn't the endpoints be ($\a_{n}, \b_{n}$)

Comment: What have you tried? Can you play with some examples to see what sorts of things can happen?

Answer (score 6):

I find it difficult to give only a hint without giving the answer, so I'll present the formula right away and leave it to you to prove that it's correct and to figure out why it includes both possible cases.
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^n(a_i,b_i)=\left(\max_{i=1}^n{a_i},\ \min_{i=1}^n b_i\right)$$