# intersection of finite intervals in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying some properties of Real Numbers. I have a claim that graphically seems true, but I don't know how to prove it.

Let $p_i,r_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ be real numbers such that $p_1<p_2<\cdots<p_n$, and for all $i, j$ we have
$$|p_i-p_j|\leq r_i+r_j$$
Then $\bigcap I_k$ is a point or contains an interval, where $I_k$ denotes the closed interval centred at $p_k$ with radius $r_k$.

The case $n=2$ is immediate and for $n=3$ the condition over the distance between the centers guarantees that the intervals are not so far apart, but I don't see how to generalize this.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544949/the-intersection-of-open-intervals

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint: any arbitrary intersection of intervals is either, empty, a point, or an interval. So you only need show that it is non-empty.

Here is another hint: combine two intervals into one. The question is, which two intervals?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm working in a deeper problem, and I need to take a point in that intersection. So the dificult part (in my case) is to show that this intersection is non-empty.